# Unable to find server client secret of my project using Oauth

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-oauth

I am new to android development. I am in a situation where I need the gender and date of birth for the user who signed in using their google account.

For this I am using the code which is shown below

```
class GetGendersTask extends AsyncTask<GoogleSignInAccount, Void, List<Gender>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Gender> doInBackground(GoogleSignInAccount... googleSignInAccounts) {
        List<Gender> genderList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            //Redirect URL for web based applications.
            // Can be empty too.
            String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

            // Exchange auth code for access token
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    httpTransport,
                    jsonFactory,
                    getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_id),
                    getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_secret),
                    googleSignInAccounts[0].getServerAuthCode(),
                    redirectUrl
            ).execute();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(
                            getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_id),
                            getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.server_client_secret)
                    )
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .build();

            credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

            People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("My Application Name")
                    .build();

            // Get the user's profile
            Person profile = peopleService.people().get("people/me").execute();
            genderList.addAll(profile.getGenders());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return genderList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Gender> genders) {
        super.onPostExecute(genders);
        // iterate through the list of Genders to
        // get the gender value (male, female, other)
        for (Gender gender : genders) {
            String genderValue = gender.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

To sucessfully execute the code which is shown above, I need the server_client_id and server_client_secret. After going into my application's developer console, I found out my server_client_id but unfortunately I am not able to find the server_client_secret key. 
I have surfed a lot and didn't end up finding the answer. I knew that many people have already addressed this query. But sorry to tell this that I am not able to find the answer.

Could anyone help me get through this issue.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't use client secrets. Since it's a device the user holds, it wouldn't be a secret for long. If you need a client secret for your project, go to the dev console and create an additional set of credentials, specifying Web App.

Comment: So is there any other way to get the personal info like gender and DOB without using this server client secret key?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get and the many questions on SO that already ask that question. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349747/unable-to-get-user-profile-from-google-using-google-apis-in-android